# Versioning in the database

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I want to store full versioning of the row every time a update is made for amount sensitive table.

So far, I have decided to use the following approach.

1. Do not allow updates.
2. Every time a update is made create a new
   entry in the table.

However, I am undecided on what is the best database structure design for this change.

**Current Structure**

Primary Key: id

```
id(int) | amount(decimal) | other_columns
```

**First Approach**

Composite Primary Key: id, version

```
id(int) | version(int) | amount(decimal) | change_reason 
 1      | 1            | 100             | 
 1      | 2            | 20              | correction
```

**Second Approach**

Primary Key: id

Uniqueness Index on [origin_id, version]

```
id(int) | origin_id(int) | version(int) | amount(decimal) | change_reason 
 1      | NULL           |  1           | 100             | NULL
 2      | 1              |  2           | 20              | correction
```

Comment: you could make a AFTER or BEFORE UPDATE trigger to record the change.. And make a VIEW to calculate the version something like ... `CREATE VIEW AS SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY created ASC) AS version, ...`

Comment: If you store an Effective_Date instead of version, you can not only determine the most recent version, but also when each successive version became effective.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I ended up using triggers with a separate table for historical changes. This was a very useful comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a new table which store `unique id` for item. This serves as lookup table for all available items.

**item** Table:

```
id(int)
1000
```

For the table which stores all changes for `item`, let's call it `item_changes` table. `item_id` is a `FOREIGN KEY` to `item` table's `id`. The relationship between `item` table to `item_changes` table, is `one-to-many` relationship.

**item_changes** Table:

```
id(int) | item_id(int)   | version(int) | amount(decimal) | change_reason 
 1      | 1000           |  1           | 100             | NULL
 2      | 1000           |  2           | 20              | correction
```

With this, `item_id` will never be `NULL` as it is a valid `FOREIGN KEY` to `item` table.

Comment: So, The actual attributes will be stored in the item_changes table and the item table is only for storing the unique id?

Comment: @xeon131 Yes, that's the idea. But of course you name your tables accordingly as you like.

Comment: Just going through what I implemented differently from this answer. I kept the items table for the current record and added another table item_changes just for recording changes made to the item. I added after create triggers on the items table to insert the old record to the item_changes table on INSERT and UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

The best method is to use Version Normal Form (vnf). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478331/how-to-best-manage-historical-lookup-values-in-a-database/47505253#47505253) is an answer I gave for a neat way to track all changes to specific fields of specific tables.

The static table contains the static data, such as PK and other attributes which do not change over the life of the entity or such changes need not be tracked.

The version table contains all dynamic attributes that need to be tracked. The best design uses a view which joins the static table with the current version from the version table, as the current version is probably what your apps need most often. Triggers on the view maintain the static/versioned design without the app needing to know anything about it.

The link above also contains a link to a document which goes into much more detail including queries to get the current version or to "look back" at any version you need.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are not going for **SCD-2** (Slowly Changing Dimension), which is a rule/methodology to describe the best solution for your problem. Here is the SCD-2 advantage and example for using, and it makes standard design pattern for the database.

Type 2 - Creating a new additional record. In this methodology, all history of dimension changes is kept in the database. You capture attribute change by adding a new row with a new surrogate key to the dimension table. Both the prior and new rows contain as attributes the natural key(or other durable identifiers). Also 'effective date' and 'current indicator' columns are used in this method. There could be only one record with the current indicator set to 'Y'. For 'effective date' columns, i.e. start_date, and end_date, the end_date for current record usually is set to value 9999-12-31. Introducing changes to the dimensional model in type 2 could be very expensive database operation so it is not recommended to use it in dimensions where a new attribute could be added in the future.

```
id | amount | start_date    |end_date       |current_flag
1    100      01-Apr-2018    02-Apr-2018     N
2    80       04-Apr-2018    NULL            Y
```

Detail Explanation::::

Here, all you need to add the 3 extra column, **START_DATE, END_DATE, CURRENT_FLAG** to track your record properly. When the first time record inserted @ source, this table will be store the value as:

```
id | amount | start_date    |end_date       |current_flag
1    100      01-Apr-2018    NULL            Y
```

And, when the same record will be updated then you have to update the "END_DATE" of the previous record as current_system_date and "CURRENT_FLAG" as "N", and insert the second record as below. So you can track everything about your records. as below...

```
id | amount | start_date    |end_date       |current_flag
1    100      01-Apr-2018    02-Apr-2018     N
2    80       04-Apr-2018    NULL            Y
```